# Asking a teacher for more (hopefully extra credit) homework

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, grammar-choice, syntax

Salvete, Sodales!

I'm a student in his second year of Latin study, but my class has been slow in reading our texts and I've been bored from the beginning. I want to ask my teacher to give me more homework, particularly for extra credit. Please help with my translation; change it, improve it, or submit something different that gets the point across. Bonus points if your addition comes from an attested source.

---

Nicolas cordo sal.

Solum(or Unum?) desiderium quem habeo. Valeo legere litteras missas ad legendum, at plus desidero. Mittas mihi plus ut numerus punctorum alat. Opportetne factu?

Vale.

---

This is intended to mean the following (roughly translated):
There is one desire that I have. I am able to read the literature given for reading BUT I want more. Please give me more so that I get more points. Could we do that?

Comment: Choose *Unum,* and then leave out *quem,* which is wrong AND is unnecessary, because Latin is more concise. After that I suggest you change nothing, even if it is not yet Cicero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm only at an intermediate level of Latin, but I thought I'd make an attempt to express your request. Maybe there's something here you can use—or an error here that someone will catch.

Here's a more prosaic version:

> Lectiones praescriptas legere potui ultraque cupio. Dabisne mihi plures lectiones itaque plura puncta meream?

And here's a more histrionic version:

> Lubenti animo omnes lectiones praescriptas adhuc voravi tamenque non satiatur appetentia mea. Opus est mihi plure materiae ad legendum, lectiones enim egeo, immo deficiente lectionibus cotidie fame pereo. O magister, oro te, oro te, ala me, ala me! (Praesumo te ad notas meas lectiones super eas pro cursu postulatas additurum esse.)